Is it possible to rollback to 22.04.4 somehow?
I upgraded from 22.04.4 to 24.04.1 a few days ago and so far it's really feeling like a downgrade to me.
The upgrade itself required me fixing a black background and sudo apt-get install -f to get the software updater working again. Also the usual killall snap-store to get the new app center.
But after fixing that I still have a ton of problems:

My laptop battery drains a lot faster
Sometimes scrolling through browser pages or code in Godot for example is stuttery and not fluent at all
Brave browser doesn't work properly anymore and draws a black border when resizing it but takes seconds to actually resize the window to that black border it draws.
It takes way longer(12 seconds on average) to get my laptop out of suspense when I close&open the lid than it did in 22.04(1-4 seconds), sometimes when coming out of suspense it turns up the screen to maximum brightness and doesn't remember my previous brightness setting.
When I plug in my power cord, my Dock with icons seems to "reload".
This also happens each time I toggle Power Modes in the menu top-right.
Keyboard input sometimes leaks through windows that I have in focus, sometimes when I type something in VS Code and switch to Godot for example I see a few letters at the spot where my cursor was positioned before I switched windows
In Nautilus sometimes files stay "slightly" selected randomly, but not the full gray outline they have when they're selected. I can't seem to find out when it happens, it's not when I've opened that file for example
Clicking things in the top bar(app indicators? or how are they called) takes significantly longer to open than on 22.04, Telegram for example used to show me the menu instantly but now when I click the Telegram icon it takes about 1,5-2 seconds for the menu to show. Same as for VLC player(which doesn't even have an icon anymore). Dropbox menu doesn't even work most of the time.
When enabling fractional scaling it didn't change anything when I changed the %, but when I disabled it again it made me have a constrained/boxed screen like I'm in a VM. So it used up about 50% of my screen and the rest of the monitor was black and unreachable with the mouse.
When I put a window of an application(like gnome settings) to the left half of my screen with super + left it seems to have a quite glitchy animation, but when I used super + left again afterwards it moved my window 50% off the screen on the left side in an unreachable place(without having an extra monitor connected). I could replicate this on the right side. Doesn't seem to happen anymore after a few reboots luckily.

The only thing that I changed after the upgrade was disabling Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Tiling Assistant in the extension settings and re-enabling Dash to Dock again since Ubuntu Dock doesn't have the rounded corners I want like I had on 22.04.
I'd love to know if it's possible to safely rollback or if others have had a different experience with a similar system configuration like mine:
Lenovo yoga slim 7
Ryzen 4800U (Vega 8 iGPU)
16GB DDR4 RAM
4TB m.2 SSD
Thanks in advance :)

Going back to 22.04 might manage the immediate problems.  I too have noticed some significant performance problems.  In my case, the performance issues where with 32MB USB flash drives.  I don't know how to revert an upgraded system.  I always install the new LTS on a different hard drive on a separate system then switch over if it looks good.  If it doesn't look good, it's important to pursue resolving the issues found.  Unless people make it known 24.04 is not working well for them (filing bugs maybe) - 26.04 and 28.04 are probably going to have problems as well.

About the time 28.04 comes out, the moderators of askubuntu.com will not look kindly on questions related to release 22.04.

A few months before your next release-upgrade comes around, please help test. Had a community member with your configuration tested and reported the bugs early, your experience might have been much better. Testing is how many community members contribute to Ubuntu.

In future always take a clone before performing any unreversable updates.

Thanks for the answers everyone.
I'll just work with 2 SSDs from now on and test the new release with a fresh install on the new one. The upgrade path from LTS to LTS never worked flawlessly for me so I think that's a better solution.

There is no supported "rollback".
Packages can be downgraded using apt's --downgrade flag, but nobody has tried downgrading an entire desktop stack and returned to tell the tale.
The only supported method is a reinstall of the older release.

That's what I thought and is even more reason I won't install a new LTS over the current one - always making a fresh install on a different hard drive.

Thank you, I think this isn't the way to go either.
I'll follow quill's advice and just work with 2 SSDs for any next LTS release.
